# In WPF, how to get the name of a control by its tag in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tags

I have some `Button`s with a `Tag` attribute:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Tag="1" />
<Button x:Name="Button2" Tag="2" />
<Button x:Name="Button3" Tag="3" />
<!-- etc. -->
```

I want to be able to find the name of the `Button` from code-behind, using the tag. How to accomplish that? Thanks.

Comment: For what reason? If you can access the Tag property, you already have the Button. You might add some details of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: could you explain when and why you want to do this?

Comment: @Clemens - I do not have the button. I have a function that generates a number, and I want to choose the button base on that number. Now, the `Tag` attribute is meant to hold custom data, so I thought it is a good choice to put that number there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all name the container of buttons (For example I named it "Grid1")
Here is the code to find your button:

```
var foundButton = Grid1.Children.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Tag.ToString() == "2").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the MVVM patter using RelayCommand...

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Button1" x:Name="Button1" Tag="1" Command="{Binding ButtonPressCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        <Button Content="Button2" x:Name="Button2" Tag="2" Command="{Binding ButtonPressCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        <Button Content="Button3" x:Name="Button3" Tag="3" Command="{Binding ButtonPressCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

You should be passing the 'Tag' value back to the ViewModel as a  CommandParameter

Comment: And how to get it from the code behind? Thanks a lot.